# ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries while re-running CMake

Tags: c, clion

I am encountering an error while trying to re-run CMake for my project. The error message reads:

```
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: path_of_the_program/cmake-build-debug
ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries
```

I am not sure what is causing this error, and I have not been able to find any information online that can help me resolve it. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this error, and how I can resolve it?

Here is some additional information that might be helpful:

- I am using CMake version 3.24 and Ninja version 1.10.2
- I am running this on a Windows machine
- The project I am trying to build is a C project
- I have tried deleting the entire build directory and rebuilding the project from scratch, but the error persists

Comment: Is the system time correct? Do you have any files with a modification time in the future? Please [edit] your question to provide requested information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Indeed, @Bodo. The system clock appears to be correct, and I have not come across any files that exhibit a modified timestamp.

Comment: **Please [edit] your question and add requested information to the question.** To allow us to verify this, can you show a full directory listing of your project's files, e.g. copy&paste the output of `dir /s` *as text*? (Unfortunately I don't currently have more ideas what could be wrong.)